# Google Content Api for Shopping - List only wanted product features

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-shopping-api

I am utilizing the script below (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/shopping-content) I am wondering, instead of all the resources, how could I just list the product price for example?

```js
/**
 * Lists the products for a given merchant.
 */
function productList() {
  var merchantId = 123456; // Replace this with your Merchant Center ID.
  var pageToken;
  var pageNum = 1;
  var maxResults = 10;
  do {
    var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
      pageToken: pageToken,
      maxResults: maxResults
    });
    Logger.log('Page ' + pageNum);
    if (products.resources) {
      for (var i = 0; i < products.resources.length; i++) {
        Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] ==> ' + products.resources[i]);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No more products in account ' + merchantId);
    }
    pageToken = products.nextPageToken;
    pageNum++;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] ==> ' + products.resources[i]);
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] (product price) ==> ' + products.resources[i].price.value); // or products.resources[i].price.currency
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the data as an array, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function productList() {
      var merchantId = 123456; // Replace this with your Merchant Center ID.
      var pageToken;
      var pageNum = 1;
      var maxResults = 10;
      var res = []; // Added
      do {
        var products = ShoppingContent.Products.list(merchantId, {
          pageToken: pageToken,
          maxResults: maxResults
        });
        Logger.log('Page ' + pageNum);
        if (products.resources) {
          for (var i = 0; i < products.resources.length; i++) {
            res.push({id: products.resources[i].id, title: products.resources[i].title, price: products.resources[i].price.value}); // Added
            Logger.log('Item [' + i + '] (product price) ==> ' + products.resources[i].price.value); // or products.resources[i].price.currency
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('No more products in account ' + merchantId);
        }
        pageToken = products.nextPageToken;
        pageNum++;
      } while (pageToken);
      Logger.log(res); // Added
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to use `ShoppingContent.Products.list()` method. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: products.list](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/reference/rest/v2.1/products/list)
- [Price](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/reference/rest/v2.1/Price)